# How to get the reverse result to a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am using the following sql query to get the name of a branch that has submitted a report.

```
SELECT DISTINCT branch.b_name AS branch from branch, report_activity2

where branch.branch_id=report_activity2.branch_id 

and week =16
and year =2022
```

What I would also like to do is get the names of branches that have not submitted a report for the same week and year. I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT branch.b_name FROM branch

WHERE branch_id not in

(SELECT DISTINCT branch.b_name AS branch from branch, report_activity2

where branch.branch_id=report_activity2.branch_id 

and week =16
and year =2022)
```

But the second query result lists all the branches and does not exclude the branch from the first query. I am not sure if I am doing this completely wrong or I have just missed something simple. Any help to nudge me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You are checking whether a `branch_id` occurs in a list of `branch.b_name`. Either check id's or check names, but don't check id's against names. If you fix that, you'll have a better solution than the accepted answer. Also: You don't need a `DISTINCT` in the `IN` query. And it's 2022, ansi '92 `JOIN` syntax is 30 years old, high time to use it. Comma separated join syntax is harder to write (correctly), harder to read and more difficult to maintain (change to outer join, for example). Finally, qualify your columns, it is not immediately clear which table has the columns `week` and `year`

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Thanks for your help and advice there is a lot of learning for me here, much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first one you don't really need distinct and also you shouldn't use the old style join anyway:

```
SELECT b_name AS branch from branch
where exists (select * from report_activity2
where branch.branch_id=report_activity2.branch_id
and report_activity2.week =16
and report_activity2.year =2022);
```

In the second one you should compare branch_id to branch_ or b_name to b_name (provided it is unique) but you were checking branch_id in (... b_bame ...). Anyway it also doesn't need a join:

```
SELECT b_name AS branch from branch
where NOT exists (select * from report_activity2
where branch.branch_id=report_activity2.branch_id
and report_activity2.week =16
and report_activity2.year =2022);
```

EDIT: Some more explanation.
With EXISTS (...), per row of branch, we are checking if in report_activity2 there is a row where branch_id matches "current" branch.branch_id and week = 16 and year 2022. If a match is found then it acts as a true on filtering branch. The good part is, there might be 1 or 1000 matching rows, it wouldn't matter and unlike a join it would just stop finding the first match thus more performant than doing a join (in which case you also would need to have DISTINCT, if there were 1000 rows matching a particular branch.branch_id, you first get 1000 rows and then DISTINCT select 1 one them).
Somewhat visual explanation:

Branch:

```
Branch_id, b_name
1, 'b1'
2, 'b2'
```

Report_Activity2:

```
Branch_Id, Week, Year, ...
1,  1, 2022
1, 16, 2022
1, 16, 2022
1, 16, 2022
2,  1, 2022
```

With join it looks like (3 matches for 1):

```
1, 'b1', 1, 16, 2022
1, 'b1', 1, 16, 2022
1, 'b1', 1, 16, 2022
```

and then you use DISTINCT on b_name to get 'b1'.

With exists:

On

```
  1, 'b1'
```

a match is found thus it immediately returns a true on first

```
1, 16, 2022
```

without checking other rows in report_activity2. Resulting set is already:

1, 'b1'

Thus you don't need a DISTINCT hack.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, your answer also works perfectly and thanks for your tip on restructuring both queries. I will need to study more to make sure I fully understand your answers. I thought I needed distinct because for each week there will be more than one record for each branch. That's the bit in your code that works great but I need to study more. Thanks again.

Comment: This is a much better solution than the (now) accepted answer. It will probably perform much better, and is much clearer in intention

Comment: @codestruggler, I added some explanation about how it works.

Comment: @ Cetin Basoz Wow! that’s an awesome explanation, thank you very much for taking the time and trouble not only to answer my question but also to provide a detailed and thorough breakdown of how and why your solution works.  Very much appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: @ Cetin Basoz I have tried adding two additional columns to the above query you very kindly created. The column names are franchise, which is in the branch table and region which is in the region table. The query gets the correct franchise and region for each for each branch, but no longer gives just one result per branch as it does in your query above. I am sure the solution lies in the answer you have already given but I have missed it some how. I would be great if you could nudge me in the right direction. I

Comment: Here is the full query
```
SELECT  branch.b_name AS branch,branch.franchise, region.name AS region from branch,region
where NOT exists (select * from report_activity2
where branch.branch_id=report_activity2.branch_id
and  report_activity2.region_id = branch.region_id             
and report_activity2.week =16
and report_activity2.year =2022);
```

Comment: @codestruggler, there is a new table in the equation and there is no relation set between the two. Also you are attempting to create old style join, which you shouldn't. Probably what you meant is:  SELECT branch.b_name AS branch,branch.franchise, region.name AS region 
 from branch
 inner join region on branch.region_id = region.id and  
 where NOT exists (select * 
     from report_activity2 
  where branch.branch_id=report_activity2.branch_id and 
        report_activity2.region_id = branch.region_id and 
     report_activity2.week =16 and 
     report_activity2.year =2022);

Comment: @Cetin Basoz Thanks again for your help, been going round in circles for days getting nowhere before your help. Just corrected a few typo's in your new code. Removed the and before the where and changed region,region.id to region.region_id and it works perfectly. How you can answer my questions without seeing the tables is amazing. I will need to study joins some more. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

can you try this mysql command ?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT branch.b_name AS branch from branch, report_activity2

where branch.branch_id != report_activity2.branch_id 

and week =16
and year =2022 ;
```